# Como agregar UTF8 a la conexión de la base de datos Mysql

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Me gustaria saber si alguine me podria ayudar en indicarme como agregar utf8 a la conexión de mi base de datos.
Tengo dos problemas , uno de ellos ya resuelto, al mostrar los datos de las tablas en mi sitio web resulta que se mostraban los acentos y la letra ñ en forma de triángulos negros con un signo de pregunta, la letra ñ la resolvi cambiando el valor de cada tabla a latin1_swedish_ci, sin embargo esto no resuelve los acentos.
Lei que mediante la conexión a la base de datos se debe hacer algo parecido a esto.

### $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8", $user, $password);

Sin embargo soy sincero, no tengo mucho conocimiento en esto y la verdad no se como integrar esto a mi coneccion actual.
Aca dejo mi conexión actual a la bd

`````
class Database
{
    private static $dbHost = "localhost";
    private static $dbName = "nombre_db";
    private static $dbUsername = "user_db";
    private static $dbUserpassword = "pass_db";
    
    private static $connection = null;
    
    public static function connect()
    {
        if(self::$connection == null)
        {
            try
            {
              self::$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . self::$dbHost . ";dbname=" . self::$dbName , self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserpassword);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }
    
    public static function disconnect()
    {
        self::$connection = null;
    }

}
?>````
`````

Comment: Colocalo en una propiedad y luego concatenalo dentro de tu cadena de conexión

Comment: Ni idea de que hablas :(

Comment: Lo que te estoy proponiendo es basado en lo que veo que ya tienes, asi como declaraste otras propiedades, una mas para lo que necesitas agregar y luego concatenala a lo que ya escribiste

Comment: Lo he hecho asi pero no me funciona ````self::$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . self::$dbHost . ";dbname=" . self::$dbNamedbname=database;charset=utf8 , self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserpassword);````